# Does every aperiodic 2-adic number whose corresponding real is algebraic, have a representation as a periodic p-adic for some other p?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, continued-fractions

**Question**

Does every aperiodic 2-adic number whose corresponding real is algebraic, have a representation as a periodic p-adic for some other p?

**More concrete**

I'm aware that the members of two p-adic fields are incomparable unless both fields are subfields of some larger field, but I believe this circumvents that objection:

Truncate a $1:x$ rectangle shape by cutting a $1\times1$ square off its shortest end to form a new rectangle shape, and rescale up to $1:x$

Every time you truncate from the same end as you started, record a $1$,  Every time you truncate from the opposite end, write a $0$.

This forms a bijection $f:\Bbb R^{\geq0}\to\Bbb Z_2$ between the real numbers greater than or equal to zero, and the 2-adic numbers.  The bijection conjugates inverses in the reals to $-x$ in the 2-adics.

Since writing the 2-adic number is topologically conjugate to writing a continued fraction, it is a corollary of theorems of Lagrange and Euler that $f$ bijects the *periodic* 2-adic numbers with the set of all quadratic roots.

Now if periodicity fails for $p=2$, switch to the map truncating 3-hyperrectangles and 3-adics and so on.

My conjecture is that every algebraic number which is aperiodic in $\Bbb Z_2$ is periodic in some other p-adic field.  Is there a proof, counterexample or reference?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean.  A periodic $p$-adic, i.e. a $p$-adic with representation $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i p^i$ where the sequence $a_i$ is periodic, is a rational number.  An irrational algebraic number is not going to have a periodic $p$-adic expansion for any $p$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thank-you for looking at my question. if you read the question, the "correspondemce" it uses derives any algebraic number's p-adic from the number's continued fraction representation rather than by directly writing its its base p representation mod $p^n$ whereas I assume from your comment you have assumed the latter.

Comment: A continued fraction is terminating if and only if the number is rational.

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes, and periodic if and only if the number is a quadratic root (the theorem of Lagrange and Euler that I mention). This question takes that as a premise, describes it in terms of truncating rectangle shapes (which is the same as continued fractions) and then goes on to ask whether truncating higher dimensional hyperrectangles could give the solutions to polynomials of higher degree than $2$.

Comment: Apologies @RobertIsrael maybe I misunderstood you, but by aperiodic I mean neither periodic nor constant, i.e. I'm excluding all $\Bbb Z\subset\Bbb Z_2$ which are eventually constant $\overline0_2$ and $\overline1_2$. So by aperiodic I mean in a sense the "irrational 2-adics".

Comment: @RobertIsrael FWIW I have since discovered that the function I have discovered for myself above here is actually Minkowski's question mark function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question-mark_function  That does not at the moment help inform me of what the non-quadratic irrationals would map to, but it does make what I thought an interesting question even more interesting and I have not yet given up.